# What can be java programm startup parameters? Does exist a list?

Tags: java, parameters, startup

Sometimes I see like:

```
-D
```

or
    -X

that passed to jdk/bin/java...
Where I can find complete list of these parameters?

Comment: Look in the javadocs under tools for java.exe.

Comment: Have you tried reading the docs, or typing `java -help`?

Comment: Docs are very big. It is not clear what does it mean D or X (why not A B C Y ...?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard options (and some common non-standard ones) are listed in the [documentation of the java command](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).

There are also a lot of vendor-specific non-standard options for [tuning and debugging the VM's behaviour](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html), especially garbage collection.

Answer (score 3):

just go to the bin dir of the jdk into the cmd(command prompt) and type java and enter

like this way

[image]

Comment: +1; Maybe you should add that the `-X` option is one of the interesting ones :-)

Answer (score 2):

at the command line type java -? and java -X to see a list of options and their explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Look there: http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Answer (score 1):

The man page, or running the executable with the `-help` flag, will display the standard parameters.

For Sun-VM specific `-XX:...` options, there's a list at [Java Hotspot VM Options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) - though by definition this is JVM-specific, and you may wish to search for a similar page if you're using an alternative VM.